# Pattern matching in R if string NOT followed but another string

Tags: r, regex, string, pattern-matching, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to match the following in R using str_detect from the stringr package.

I want to to detect if a given string if followed or preceeded by 'and' or '&'. For example, in:

```
string_1<-"A and B"
string_2<-"A B"
string_3<-"B and A"
string_4<-"A B and C"
```

I want str_detect(string_X) to be FALSE for string_1, string_3 and string_4 but TRUE for string_2.

I have tried:

```
str_detect(string_X,paste0(".*(?<!and |& )","A"))==TRUE & str_detect(string_X,paste0(".*","A","(?! and| &).*"))==TRUE)
```

I use paste0 because I want to run this over different strings. This works all the cases above except 4. I am new to regex, and it also does not seem very elegant. Is there a more general solution?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a positive lookahead assertion to make sure that there is no `A` or `B` present followed by `and` or `&` and also not in the other order.

```
^(?!.*[AB] (?:and|&))(?!.*(?:and|&) [AB])
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?!.*[AB] (?:and|&))` Assert that the string does not contain `A` or `B` followed by either and or &
- `(?!.*(?:and|&) [AB])` Assert that the string does not contain either and or & followed by either A or B

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bZSpa5/1) | [R demo](https://tio.run/##K/r/PyczqSixqFKjuKQoMy@9SJOLC8KKN7TRVXJUSMxLUXBSgokZgcUQfGMg3wmsxhEuZgJRAxZ1houaAkXVQDqhAsUKNroKyRowu3QUYDbAWcZwlgmcZQpxXnxKaklqcglUd7GOglKchr2inla0o1Osgoa9FdDqGjVNTbAYnKsAktVU0uT6/x8A)

```
library(stringr)

string_1<-"A and B"
string_2<-"A B"
string_3<-"B and A"
string_4<-"A B and C"
string_5<-"& B"

strings <- c(string_1, string_2, string_3, string_4, string_5)

str_detect(strings, "^(?!.*[AB] (?:and|&))(?!.*(?:and|&) [AB])")
```

Output

```
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Answer (score 2):

First let's combine your four strings into a single vector:

```r
strings <- c(string_1, string_2, string_3, string_4)
```

Now using

```r
library(stringr)

str_detect(strings, "(A|B)(?=\\s(and|&))", negate = TRUE)
```

we look for "A" or "B" followed by "and" or "&". So this returns

```r
#> [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

You could wrap it into a function:

```r
detector <- function(letters, strings) {
  pattern <- paste0("(", paste0(letters, collapse = "|"), ")(?=\\s(and|&))")
  str_detect(strings, pattern, negate = TRUE)
}

detector(c("A", "B"), strings)
#> [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE

detector(c("A"), strings)
#> [1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE

detector(c("B"), strings)
#> [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE

detector(c("C"), strings)
#> [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```